# How to have each Joomla registered user set individual sortable order using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, joomla2.5

I plan to create a grouping of sortable areas on a page using http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets and would ideally like for each user to customize the order that would then stay in place for them whenever they visit the site.

Creating the sortable areas and the items to be dragged / dropped into them is easy enough.

How would I accomplish saving the order so that it is unique for each user?

I am using Joomla 2.5, btw.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the serialize method: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

This will allow you to get and save the current sort order.

Comment: Will it be unique for each user? And if the user leaves and comes back a few days later, will the order still be saved?

Comment: @Cynthia  Using the sortable `serialize` method you need to decide where you want the data stored. You could use localStorage with a cookie fallback for older non compatible browsers or send the data to server and store with suitable method there. Use ajax to send array each time a change is made. You then need to reverse provcess for new page loads and apply last sort to elements. This could be done with php if data stored server side or with jquery afer page loads